# How to pass proper argument when deploying

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to deploy a contract with the arguments:

```
 constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address _marketingWallet
    )
```

And this is my deploy.je

```
const token = await Token.deploy("MYTOKEN", "TOK", 1000000000, "0x047B2f4Da90dA60916CbB007158f3900BcF3084f"); // I changed the value of the marketing address publicly
```

However, i got the error when deploying:

```
npx hardhat run --network testnet scripts/deploy.js
Deploying contracts with the account: 
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1)
    at makeError (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:841:22)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:747:39)
    at main (C:\Users\son\Documents\Crypto Tuto\Hardhat_testbsc\scripts\deploy.js:21:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'address'
```

Any idea where the error may come from ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an incorrect type of address.

You can easily check the validity of any address using any *web3* library, or by using online platforms like https://www.rfctools.com/ethereum-address-validator/.